# Python3: An example string that would cause UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python-3.x, unicode

I am trying to find a string, that would raise `UnicodeEncodeError`:

```
dirty_str = 'FC Bayern München'   # or anything else possible
dirty_str.encode('utf-8')
```

Whatever I have given to the input, it never raises an exception :S Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: Your input is a Unicode string. Every Unicode string can be encoded in UTF-8. I'm not sure why this would be surprising. Why do you expect an exception? Also, have you tried varying the encoding: e.g., replacing `'utf-8'` with `'ascii'`, and then entering a string that contains non-ASCII characters?

Comment: @MarkDickinson You are right, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Surrogates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_code_point) (D800—DBFF and DC00—DFFF) will raise when encoded:

```
>>> '\ud83d\udca9'.encode()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: surrogates not allowed
```

However, since you are getting the string from `input()`, there is no UTF-8 string you can input that will decode to these code points. (On Linux systems, though, Python will use these to represent invalid UTF-8 bytes in path and file names.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment :) However `'\ud83d\udca9'.encode()` returns `'\\ud83d\\udca9'` to me. You are right, forget about  `input()`, that was a wrong example.

Comment: Interesting. What are the values of `sys.version` and `sys.maxunicode`?

Comment: Also, what's the output of `sys.getdefaultencoding()`?

Comment: They are: `'3.6.5 (default, Apr 30 2018, 13:54:44) \n[GCC 7.3.0]'`, `1114111`, `'utf-8'`

Comment: @chefarov: It seems highly unlikely that `'\ud83d\udca9'.encode()` could return something that's not a bytestring. Are you _sure_ it's giving you `'\\ud83d\\udca9'`.