# How To Crash UTF-8 Encode

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, character-encoding

I am looking for a string that will crash python3 when encoding it to UTF8.

```
s=?
s.encode("UTF-8") -> results in error
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Why do you think such a string exists?

Comment: I'm not sure it exists, i need it to solve a CTF. There might be another way though..

Comment: Sorry, what's a CTF?

Comment: An error isn't the same as a crash, you can generally catch an exception to keep the program running.

Comment: @Mark Ransom yes, you are right. In this case I need python to throw an error and to execute code in the catch block.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51972941/python3-an-example-string-that-would-cause-unicodeencodeerror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UTF-8 encoder does not allow Unicode strings to use the the UTF-16 "surrogate" code points from U+D800 to U+DFFF:

```
>>> s = '\ud800'
>>> s.encode('UTF-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\ud800' in position 0: surrogates not allowed
```

Comment: wow, thanks a lot. That is exactly what I need!